# Is test automation on CI/CD really trustable?

Tags: testing, automation, continuous-integration

I was running a project with test automation on CI/CD and suddenly I got a question.

Is test automation on CI/CD really trustable?

The reason why I get this question is below.

For example, let's assume that I edit some codes on branch A and other codes on branch B and I make PRs.

As I made a test automation, The codes on branch A and branch B would be tested automatically and let's say two tests are passed.

However what if do the two parts of edited codes have no merge conflicts but interact each other and make bugs?

Then how could I trust the test automation and click the merge button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good question here, or, at least a situation that I have seen before. Branch A works fine, Branch B works fine but the combination of Branch A and B does not work.

I am going to assume that the automated tests catch the issue. So essentially flow of builds looks like this:

- Tip of master passes.
- Branch A passes.
- Branch B passes.
- Branch A is merged and tip of master passes.
- Branch B is merged and the tip of master fails.

In this case the automation in CI/CD is trustable. As it accurately reports that the problem was caused by merging B. You can quickly return to a working state by:

1. Reverting the changes from B (at which point master is now passing).

Then you can get branch B ready to merge again.

2. Rebasing branch B on the current master.
3. Fixing the issue.
4. Testing / Reviewing and Merging branch B.

I am sure you are thinking that if you are the owner of Branch B then this is a lot of work for something you hoped would be caught prior to merge. However, typically in this environment you are trying to protect the state of the master branch. I.E. above all else the master branch is in a working state. The inconvenience to one developer is outweighed by the rest of the team being able to use the working master branch.

In terms of should you trust the automation and click the merge button. I personally avoid clicking the merge button late in the day. I trust that the automation will report issues, however, I don't trust that it is perfect. I prefer to merge in the morning where I have time to react if the build after the merge fails.